# Dynamics 2016 on-premise Crm Client-Side scripting. Missing Methods for optionset control type

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I am trying to use the `Xrm.Page` API in `Dynamics CRM` to manipulate the fields on the form as follows. This should clear all the options in the control

```
var statusCodeControl = Xrm.Page.getControl('statuscode');

console.log(statusCodeControl.getControlType());

statusCodeControl.clearOptions();
```

The value optionset is being returned from `getControlType()` method but the `optionset` specific methods are missing from the object and I get the error '`clearOptions`' is not a function in the example above. I have debugged and all of the `optionset` specific methods (addOption, clearOptions, removeOption) are missing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the same code with a different option set? `statuscode` is a special field in some respects, so I'm wondering if different behavior applies which is messing up your code.

Comment: I tried on a different entity, in a different organisation, but that was also the statuscode field. I'll try it on a different field to statuscode now.

Comment: You were right. Just tried it on a new custom field, using a form local option set and that worked.

Comment: Not sure why it wouldn't work for statuscode but at least I can work around it, thanks very much for your help James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answer based on comments*

Apparently `statuscode` has some special behaviour which means this won't work. The code should work with other option set fields.